# Ubuntu shows disk volumes as one partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive

When I was installing Ubuntu(12.04 and 11.10) showed 2 partitions, whereas I have 4 partitions on Windows 7: C(70GB),D(300GB),E(300GB),F(30GB). 
Ubuntu is only 2 disks: one is 70GB, the latter is 677GB. But inside that disk there are no files from E and F. But when I checked in Windows, that files are exist.

This is what I got from `blkid`:

> /dev/sda2: UUID="deac59a9-a0d0-4a69-a918-d511a9857204" TYPE="ext4"
>   
>  /dev/sda4: UUID="C606C83106C82471" TYPE="ntfs" 
>  /dev/sda5:
>   UUID="2d3d4bf9-33b7-461c-aa88-c08caa6bef58" TYPE="swap"

And this is from `sudo fdisk -l`
[image]

How can I access that disks?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you've got from what you've written here. Please give the output from the two commands "sudo fdisk -l" and "blkid" and add them to your question.

Comment: @fabricator4, thank you, I have edited with the command results

Comment: This doesn't look right at all - Type 42 and SFS = "Secure File System", usually an encrypted partition that needs to be set up with correct cypher and algorithms to be able to read them.  Did you set up the NTFS partitions as encrypted, or is this a big mistake?  I don't know what to suggest here.  Linux does not use drive designations like 'C:' 'D:' etc.  The device names are as given in the output from the two commands you used above.

Comment: I had used truecrypt when I used Windows, do you think, it was caused something wrong, now I can not even access to that disks from Windows, when I try to install Windows 7, it doesn't detect HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install something that can install a decryption tool that can read the partitions before you can do anything with them.

Have a look at gdecrypt in the Ubuntu repositories.  Since I've never done it I will have trouble giving step by step instructions but the following is from software center page:

> gdecrypt was written for making the use of decrypted partitions under Linux more easy. It currently contains a GUI written in PyGTK for decrypting/mounting, unmounting and encrypting partitions or container files and it supports partitions created with truecrypt (see http://truecrypt.org for details) and LUKS.
>
> Note that truecrypt <=4.3a is required for truecrypt support and cryptsetup with luks is required for luks support.

You should probably edit your question with the vital truecrypt information if you want to get some help from someone who has used truecrypt.  Neither Windows nor Ubuntu come with truecrypt support out of the box so you have to install it before you can access those partitions.  This is easy enough to do with Ubuntu (select try Ubuntu then install gdecrypt) but I don't know how you will tackle Windows.